# How to use attributes from request with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Why does the alert box not work?

```
<script>
<% Player player = (Player) request.getAttribute("player"); %>
alert(<%=player.getTempId()%>);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: have u try alert(player.getTempId()); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the function returns a string. try this:

```
alert("<%=player.getTempId()%>");
```

Because if a string is returned without quotes you'll get the page to render this:

```
alert(aString) //and then you'll get an error that aString is not defined.
```

By adding "" the page will render like so:

```
alert("aString") //and will work
```